# Hiren's BootCD replacement

Tags: windows, backup, bootable

Please suggest replacement software for [Hiren's BootCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiren's_BootCD). It doen't detect my SATA hard drive as it is connected via AHCI and I can't change it in BIOS.

The tools I used from HBCD (order from the most important):

1. Driveimage XML (can be any other partition backup and restore tool with possibility to copy single file(s) from archive)
2. antivirus
3. partition manager
4. automounting USB driver
5. archive tool (like Cobian backup)

Preferences:

- GUI
- Windows based
- all software in single package

I know I can try to add driver to HBCD but I'd prefer some more recent piece of software.

Comment: Are you willing to pay, or do you want to addd the [tag:gratis] tag?

Comment: ^ and does it have to be an all-in-one solution or can it be separate software each performing its individual task?

Comment: @Tom I'd prefer single software pack (to have one pendrive with it). Although I accept multiple. I've updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [Galdalfs Windows 8.1 X86 U1 PE with Updateable USB Portable Apps](http://windowsmatters.com/2015/04/17/windows-8-1-x86-u1-pe-with-updateable-usb-portable-apps-2/).